# accessing specific threads in executor service

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

I'm currently trying to simulate a factory that builds aircrafts, the factory has 10 robots (threads) that will work on object (aircrafts) until no more are left. To do this I'm using an `ExecutorService` which has a fixed size of 10 threads. The Robots themselves are a custom class that extends thread, to stop their `run()` method from immediately finishing I have the robots have a boolean called active which I set to true like so:

```
public void run() {
        while (this.active) {
            while (this.workingAircraft == null) {
              //  System.out.println(this.getID() + " has no aircraft to work on, reporting to operator");
                try {
                    this.workingAircraft = this.op.getAircraft(this.id);
                   // System.out.println(this.toString() + " has recieved aircraft" + this.workingAircraft.getID());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                 //   System.out.println("Operator is busy");
                    try {
                        this.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                }
             if(this.workingAircraft !=null) {
                //System.out.println(this.toString() + " is working on Aircraft " + this.workingAircraft.getID());
                while (this.installAmount > 0) {
               //     System.out.println(" " + this.toString() + " :*clank* *clank*");
                    this.installAmount--;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
               // System.out.println(this.getID() + " has finished working on aircraft");
                this.returnToQueue();
                this.workingAircraft = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

The robot threads communicate with the `operator` class. This class checks to see if there are Aircrafts in an arrayBlockingQueue that belongs to a `factory` class. And if there are, assigns it to a robot thread based off some logic:

```
public synchronized Aircraft getAircraft(int id) {
        Aircraft a = this.factory.getAirCrafts().poll();
        if(a.getPartsNeeded().contains(id)){
            this.leaveWaiting(id); // remove the robot from the waitingList
            return a; //only give a robot an aircraft if it has the desired parts
        }
        this.factory.getAirCrafts().add(a);
        return null;
    }
```

I'm submitting the robots to the executor service, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            final Robot r = new Robot(this, i, operator);
            //robots.add(r);
            runningRobots.add(threadPool.submit(r));
        }
```

I have tried also adding the robots to an arrayList, and accessing them that way, however, calling methods for robots in the arrayList seems to have no effect on the threads in the executor service.

The main problem I have now is this. There is a fixed number of 10 Robot threads, However, the user running the program sets the initial amount of aircrafts. This means that I can't simply do something like `while(!queue.isEmpty()){//robot thread do work}` because the queue itself might be empty, but that doesnt mean other robots in the program have finished running their logic.

Is there any way at runtime, to access these robot objects from the executor service so I can set their active field to false after a certain period of time or condition? I have tried once submitting them to the `Executorservice` then trying to add them to an arrayList but nothing I did to the robot objects in the arraylist seemed to effect the threads in the thread pool.

Comment: There is no default to get a specific thread from the executor. A custom implementation as you did is the way to go. Share some code how you add the Threads to the List and how you access them. Maybe there is something up.

Comment: Okay will do! Thanks.

Comment: Added some more info there!